# Apostrophe-pages tag, type filter

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am creating a group of different templates as want to allow the users create different types of pages as in using different templates depending on content. That is why I would like to create a filter that will help me filter the pages by type and using the different tags included on each page.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are not very interested in arranging these pages in a tree, and would prefer that both you and the public browse them by type and tag. Is that correct?

If so you should probably be using pieces rather than pages.

Comment: Exactly! Let's say I have a blog and users can create different **types of post** (meaning different _post templates_). Users want to be able to find the posts by 6/7 different criteria, hence tags are better than a tree for UX reasons. One of those criteria is the **type** which in this case corresponds to the **type of posts** e.g. text-post, image-post or video-post. Could I be able to (1) have an **"All posts"** view page containing/listing all types of posts? and (2) filter that view/list of posts using the same criteria in the **same filter panel**, even having a piece per "post" type?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that in the following tutorial for [creating UI with apostrophe-pieces-pages](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#creating-filter-u-i-with-code-apostrophe-pieces-pages-code) when describing how to list the tags when creating the filter, the url field is missing a part. It should go as follows:

```
<ul class="tag-filters">
  {% for tag in data.piecesFilters.tags %}
    <li><a href="{{ data.page._url | build({ tags: tag.value }) }}">{{ tag.label }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your content is not structured in a tree, but rather filtered dynamically by other properties, the right direction for you is to use pieces rather than pages. See [reusable content with pieces](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html).

In particular, you'll want to look at the [filtering the list of people](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/reusable-content-with-pieces.html#filtering-the-list-of-people) section of that tutorial, which demonstrates how to create filters based on any schema field, including fields of type "select". A field of type "select" is ideal for your distinct "blog templates." You can use that field to decide what file to `include` via nunjucks from the main `show.html` template for your `apostrophe-pieces-pages` subclass.

Read on past that point and you'll learn how to power those filters with AJAX so they don't require a full page refresh, but still support SEO and build a browser history, etc.

Edited to add: some of the most relevant material, as linked to from the above tutorials, is in the article [creating UI with apostrophe-pieces-pages](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html#creating-filter-u-i-with-code-apostrophe-pieces-pages-code).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to make this work. I was just wondering if for the part `including` the file depending on selected template,  can I do that with any page or should it be only macros? Is there any tutorial on how to use macros? couldn't find any!

Comment: You want the Nunjucks documentation: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/